What is a correct mathematical abstraction of the numerical discretization of a space in computational physics
I am trying to find a correct way to abstract a computational code in physics from a mathematical standpoint. The structure I am trying to abstract is made of the following:

A continuous space $S$ representing the physical space that can either be the classical Euclidian space of Newton or a pseudo-Riemannian manifold in general relativity
An underlying discretized version of this space $D$ (stored in memory) either by a regular grid, an adaptive mesh refinement scheme, a completely unstructured mesh (see image below)
A mapping $\varphi$ from $D$ to $S$ that maps every coordinate in $D$ to a point in $S$
A mapping $\psi$ which maps every point in the continuous space $S$ to the corresponding mesh element in $D$

QUESTION: How would you abstract that in maths from a topogical, algebraic, and/or categorical standpoint? If it does not match exactly, what abstraction would come close?


I believe you are referring, somewhat obliquely, to something that is actually done in computational physics. If so, I suggest clarifying that issue.

I am a computational physicist myself. In most codes, $S$ is not represented and physicists identify $S$ to $D$. I am trying to formalize the pattern for compositional reasons.

The standard terminology is "triangulation" and "cubulation."
